# Send Email Notification when AEM Workflow failure?

Tags: java, aem

I need send Email Notification when workflow is failure, How can i create a failure workflow first?

Answer (score 0):

1) if you are using a custom workflow. you can use the API "com.day.cq.workflow.WorkflowException" and write the email triggering in your process step.

2) if you wanted to do this for all the Workflows including OOTB workflows then, you have to write a listener/CRON job for the "org/apache/sling/event/notification/job/FAILED" events to trigger your email process/workflow.